# Intersection of Events is an Event Proof Verification

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

[image]

From https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_Events_is_Event. 
I think steps 3 and 4 are problematic. Of Course from demorgan's law the union of complements is the same thing as the complement of intersections but I think demorgan's is misapplied because our universe of sets is something else.

If I were actually doing the proof I would use big union and intersection instead of just picking two elements of the event space $A$ and $B$ and say the empty set is in the big intersection.

Comment: From looking at it I think the third step has a typo as the second $A$ seems like it is supposed to be a $B$.

Comment: @WaveX Is that the only thing wrong with it?

Comment: It appears that way. Using the links within the link you provided I am able to follow along with the proof

Comment: Why do you say "our universe of sets is something else" ? Besides the typo that WaveX mentioned, the proof is correct